# why are access times to data stored in cells shorter than in matrices?

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm dealing with very big data in matlab and used to store this data in matrices. I used to store my data by row, but since Matlab stores data column-wise I understand that reshaping my matrix so I index by column makes handling faster. Here's an example of what I mean:

---

**general parameters**

```
nbr_channels = 20;
nbr_samples_per_channel = 3200000;
fake_data = randn(1, nbr_samples_per_channel);
ROI = 1200000 : 2800000;
```

**assign data by row**

```
data = nan(nbr_channels, nbr_samples_per_channel);
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    data(j, 1:nbr_samples_per_channel) = fake_data; 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 1.476525 seconds.
```

**return data from row matrix**

```
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data(j, ROI); 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.572162 seconds.
```

**return all data from row matrix**

```
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data(j, :); 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.589489 seconds.
```

**assign data by column**

```
data = nan(nbr_samples_per_channel, nbr_channels);
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    data(1:nbr_samples_per_channel, j) = fake_data; 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.299682 seconds.
```

**return data from column matrix**

```
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data(ROI, j); 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.260824 seconds.
```

**return all data from column matrix**

```
tic; 
f    or j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data(:, j); 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.092983 seconds.
```

---

**Summary Part1:**

As we can see, accessing the data by column reduces the handling times by at least a factor of two!

But I don't understand why cells are even more efficient! Have a look at this example:

**assign data by cell**

```
data = cell(1, nbr_samples_per_channel);
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    data{j} = fake_data; 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.000013 seconds.
```

**return data from cell array**

```
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data{j}(ROI); 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.260294 seconds.
```

**return all data from cell array**

```
tic; 
for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    bla = data{j}; 
end; 
toc;

% Elapsed time is 0.000022 seconds.

%%
```

---

**Summary Part2:**

This is orders of magnitude faster than what I have shown in Part1.

**Question 1**

why are access times to data stored in cells shorter than in matrices?

**Question 2**

Working with matrices is generally easier than with cells, because with a matrix on can do

`my_matrix(100:20000, 1:3)`

but with cells I can't do this (as far as I know). Any alternatives on how to return specific elements from multiple cells at the same time?

Comment: Just a small comment: when assigning, it is faster to do:
`for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    data(j,:) = fake_data; 
end;` (`1.962057 seconds.`)

than

`for j = 1 : nbr_channels
    data(j, 1:nbr_samples_per_channel) = fake_data; 
end; ` (`2.608001 seconds.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing different times because you are not doing equivalent things.  To compare two of your cases:

**assign data by cell**

- You are creating a cell array row vector, and stuffing in a long double vector to each cell
- Each loop iteration results in 1 assignment of a vector into a single slot in a cell array
- There are 'nbr_samples_per_channel' number of assignments being done.

**assign data by column**

- you are going through the columns of a matrix, and assigning a vector to each element in each column
- Each loop iteration, regardless of the shorthand colon : notation you used, resolves into many assignments.  data(1:nbr_samples_per_channel, j) means 'nbr_samples_per_channel' assignments PER iteration.
- overall, you are doing 'nbr_samples_per_channel' * 'nbr_channels' total assignments.

To make my point, just re-write the loop without the colon operator to visualize all the assignments.

```
for j = 1 : nbr_channels    

    n = length(fake_data)

    data(1,     j) = fake_data(1); 
    data(2,     j) = fake_data(1); 

    ... etc ...

    data(n - 1, j) = fake_data(n-1); 
    data(n,     j) = fake_data(n); 

end
```

So, to conclude, you are comparing two different things, so you can't say one is really faster than the other, because they are not equivalent.

If you just loop over a double array and a cell array, and do regular assignments....

```
%% Setup samples and pre-allocate
numberOfSamples = 100000;

doubleData = nan(numberOfSamples, 1);
cellData = cell(numberOfSamples, 1);

randomValues = rand(numberOfSamples, 1);

%% Assign N number of values to a double array
tic; 
for idx = 1 : numberOfSamples
    data(numberOfSamples) = randomValues(idx);
end
doubleTime = toc;

%% Assign N number of values to a cell array
tic; 
for idx = 1 : numberOfSamples
    cellData{numberOfSamples} = randomValues(idx);
end
cellTime = toc;

disp(sprintf('Double Array: %f seconds', doubleTime));
disp(sprintf('Cell   Array: %f seconds', cellTime));
```

You end up with:

```
Double Array: 0.006073 seconds
Cell   Array: 0.032966 seconds
```

---

For your second question, is this what you are trying to do?

```
>> bigCell = {1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16}

bigCell = 

    [ 1]    [ 2]    [ 3]    [ 4]
    [ 5]    [ 6]    [ 7]    [ 8]
    [ 9]    [10]    [11]    [12]
    [13]    [14]    [15]    [16]

>> subCell = bigCell(1:2, 3:4)

subCell = 

    [3]    [4]
    [7]    [8]
```

Notice that subcell is still a cell.  By using ( ) 's and not { } 's to access the cell, you preserve it being a cell.